# Проблемы после установки Python на Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

Всем привет. Начинающий линуксоид. Система Xubuntu 16.04 LTS. Решил поставить последнюю версию Python. Проверил имеющиеся версии:

- `~$ python --version` результат: Python 2.7.12,
- `~$ python3 --version` результат: Python 3.5.2,
- `which python` результат: `/usr/bin/python`
- `which python3` результат: `/usr/bin/python3`

далее...

```
~$ sudo apt update
~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6

~$ sudo apt install python3.6
~$ ls /usr/bin/python*
```

результат:

```
/usr/bin/python  /usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python2.7  
/usr/bin/python3  /usr/bin/python3.5  /usr/bin/python3.5m  
/usr/bin/python3.6  /usr/bin/python3.6m  /usr/bin/python3m

~$ python3.6 --version` результат: Python 3.6.3,
```

затем...

```
~$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
```

думаю здесь сделал ошибку, эту команду не нужно было вводить, результат:

```
update-alternatives: используется /usr/bin/python2.7 для предоставления /usr/bin/python (python) в автоматическом режиме

~$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 2
```

результат:

```
update-alternatives: используется /usr/bin/python3.5 для предоставления /usr/bin/python3 (python3) в автоматическом режиме

~$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 3
```

результат:

```
update-alternatives: используется /usr/bin/python3.6 для предоставления /usr/bin/python3 (python3) в автоматическом режиме

~$ update-alternatives --config python
```

результат:

```
 Есть только одна альтернатива в группе ссылок python (предоставляющая /usr/bin/python): /usr/bin/python2.7 Настраивать нечего.
~$ update-alternatives --config python3
```

результат:

```
Есть 2 варианта для альтернативы python3 (предоставляет /usr/bin/python3).
Выбор Путь Приор Состояние
------------------------------------------------------------
`* 0 /usr/bin/python3.6 3 автоматический режим`
`  1 /usr/bin/python3.5 2 ручной режим`
`  2 /usr/bin/python3.6 3 ручной режим`
`Press to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
```

После всех этих шаманств, начались чудеса :)

```
~$ python --version
```

получаю:

```
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: плохой интерпретатор: Нет такого файла или каталога
~$ python2 --version` возвращает: Python 2.7.12,
~$ python3 --version` возвращает: `bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: плохой интерпретатор: Нет такого файла или каталога`
~$ python3.5 --version` возвращает: Python 3.5.2,
~$ python3.6 --version` возвращает: Python 3.6.3
```

перестал запускаться `gnome-terminal` назначенный на Alt+T, возвращает: `не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal" (нет такого файла или каталога)`, но при этом запускается `gnome-terminal.real`

при запуске графического окна "Обновление приложений", выдает ошибку: `не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок "/usr/bin/update-manager" (нет такого файла или каталога)`, но при этом `sudo apt update` и `sudo apt upgrade` работают, 
при запуске графического окна "Программы и обновления", выдает ошибку: `не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk" (нет такого файла или каталога)`.

`lsb_release`
возвращает: `bash: /usr/bin/lsb_release: /usr/bin/python3: плохой интерпретатор: Нет такого файла или каталога`
`lsb_release -а`, тоже самое

попробовал все сбросить
    `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python`
    `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python2`
    `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python3`
результат: ошибки не исправились, все также. если правильно понимаю, я затронул системный python 2.7.12 и его зависимости. Помогите исправить, подскажите где я ошибся и как правильно нужно было делать.
Спасибо.

Comment: "bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3:" похоже ты сбил линки..
проверь состояние линков на питон.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку, побилась ссылка на python3.

`ls /usr/bin/python* -la`, возвращает:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 дек 6 00:55 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3542008 ноя 23 22:08 /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4464400 ноя 28 21:53 /usr/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4464400 ноя 28 21:53 /usr/bin/python3.5m
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4519936 окт 6 16:53 /usr/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4519936 окт 6 16:53 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 дек 6 00:55 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.5m
```

нет строчки python3, должна быть строка 
`/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5`

переходим в директорию `~$ cd /usr/bin/`,

создаем ссылку по имени python3, ведущую на python3.5

`sudo ln -s python3.5 python3`

проверяем создалась ли ссылка

`:/usr/bin$ ls /usr/bin/python* -la`

результат:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 дек 6 00:55 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3542008 ноя 23 22:08 /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4464400 ноя 28 21:53 /usr/bin/python3
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4464400 ноя 28 21:53 /usr/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4464400 ноя 28 21:53 /usr/bin/python3.5m
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4519936 окт 6 16:53 /usr/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4519936 окт 6 16:53 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 дек 6 00:55 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.5m
```

ссылки нет но при этом все заработало:

`:/usr/bin$ lsb_release -a`

возвращает:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

`:~$ python --version`

```
Приложение 'python' может быть найдено в следующих пакетах:
* python-minimal
* python3
Попробуйте: sudo apt install <выбранный пакет>
```

```
:~$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.12`
:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
:~$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.3
:~$ gnome-terminal
```

открывает эмулятор терминала

заработали "Обновление приложений", "Программы и обновления", пропал значок в панели о невозможности обновления. 
ссылка где нашел решение [здесь](https://toster.ru/q/486562)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было попробовать добавить репу

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

и судя по Вашей диагностике вы установили всё успешно.
дальше нужно создавать виртуальное окружение для проекта под нужную версию питона.

```
python3.6 -m venv <path>
. <path>/bin/activete
```

хэв фан..

Как исправить: проверяй состояние линка на 2.7 питон по умолчанию

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) - и работать с любой версией на выбор.

Из очевидных плюсов - может привязать интерпретатор или virtualenv к конкретному каталогу.
Если привязан virtualenv, при входе в каталог он автоматом активируется.

Установить проще через [pyenv-installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer)